# Count (*) not working with where clause

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

have an issue with a fairly basic query I'm attempting to write.

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active = null;
```

Which doesn't work. (runs, but returns 0) However, the below statement does (and returns a number), can anyone help?

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person wher date_active > '1-MAY-09';
```

I am trying to find the total number of p_ids in a table that have a date_active as null.  (They do exist, I can see them!)
Thanks

Comment: `null` never equals `null` in SQL. Do we have to have yet another question on it?

Comment: Apologies, I'm fairly rusty on this stuff, and a search of similar questions didn't help. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active is null;
```

`= null` is incorrect and won't do what you want. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) gives more detail

Answer (score 1):

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active IS null;
```

(Note the IS NULL operator instead of =)

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `is` oprator to find null:

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active is null;
```

NULL isn't a value (it indicates the absense of a vlaue), so you can't use scalar oprators like =, !=, <, > etc. in conjunction with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active IS null;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not work with binary logic (only `true` and `false`). It works with (at least) ternary logic (`true`, `false` and `null`). That third value complicates the evaluation of logical conditions (like the `=` you have in the condition).
Basically, any expression that involves a null, will return a null value, and since `null` is never `true`, the query won't return any rows, just like if you wrote

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where 1 = 2
```

To work around this there are some special syntax constructs, most common being the `is null` and `is not null` conditions. So as the other answers pointed out, to get the null values you need to write

```
select count (p_id) as mycustomer from person where date_active is null
```

---

Interesting thing about nulls is that they are neither equal not inequal to other nulls.

```
select * from person where null=null
```

and

```
select * from person where null!=null
```

both won't return any rows.

Comment: "any expression that involves a null, will return a null value" -- some expressions may **evaluate to UNKNOWN** (subtle difference): there are exceptions e.g. `IS NULL` operator evaluates to TRUE or FALSE only. UNKNOWN is a logical value in three-valued logic, whereas null is a placeholder for a value.